# MongoDB optimized way to select document count change timeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query

I want to select the progress of changing the number of documents for each day of the current week.
Users collection (very schematically): `{ _id, username (str), social (obj, default: null), createdAt (int timestamp) }`

I need to select this data:

```
// Count of the new documents per each day. Example of the data I need:
{
  all: { // Social field is null
     timeline: [Monday: 1, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 4, Thursday: 26, Friday: 24, Saturday: 30, Sunday: 47]
  },
  social: { // Social field is not null
     timeline: [Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 2, Thursday: 8, Friday: 5, Saturday: 16, Sunday: 9]
  }
}
```

Better way will be if this was aggregator.
Here is my not optimized code:

```
    let obj = { all: { timeline: [] }, social: { timeline: [] } }

    const mondayStartTime = getMonday(new Date()).getTime();
    const weekDaysStartTime = getWeekDaysStartTime(mondayStartTime);
    
    const this_week_registered = await (
        await users_collection.find({ createdAt: { $gte: mondayStartTime } })
    ).toArray();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < weekDaysStartTime.length; i++) {
        obj.all.timeline.push(
            this_week_registered.filter((obj) =>
                obj.createdAt >= weekDaysStartTime[i] && weekDaysStartTime[i + 1]
                    ? obj.createdAt < weekDaysStartTime[i + 1]
                    : true,
            ).length,
        );
        
        obj.social.timeline.push(
            this_week_registered.filter((obj) =>
                obj.social && obj.createdAt >= weekDaysStartTime[i] && weekDaysStartTime[i + 1]
                    ? obj.createdAt < weekDaysStartTime[i + 1]
                    : true,
            ).length,
        );
    }
```

I need to make this in one query.

Comment: createdAt contains change time? is it integer?

Comment: It is integer and it does not contains change time, only creation time.

Comment: How do you know whether doc changed or not?

Comment: I don't store change timestamp